# Custom columns per specific column

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm currently having a problem designing a table with custom columns,
my scenario is that I have this following tables:

User Table

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Name              |       House                |
--------------------------------------------------
| UserNameA         | 1                          |
--------------------------------------------------
```

House Table

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID                | Name                       |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1                 | House A                    |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2                 | House B                    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

This is my current design, how can I add a table that when I choose `house_id=1`

`UserNameA` user will have `custom_tag`, `custom_address`

then when I choose `house_id=2`

`UserNameA` user will have `custom_country`, `custom_phone_number`

As per output per `JSON` and Table it would be like

Scenario A in Table output

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Name              |  House | Custom Tag  | Custom Address
--------------------------------------------------------------
| UserNameA         | 1      |    Tag A    | Miami Beach, Florida 
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Scenario B in JSON output

```
{
    "name": "UserNameA:
    "house: {
        "custom_country": "turkey",
        "custom_phone_number": "+12345"
    }
}
```

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh updated my question to columns.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Please include the _exact_ expected output, formatted as a table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated it

Comment: I dont get the down-vote, you could just let me know what I needed to change.

Comment: You are missing a table which shows the key-value pairs.

Comment: This is not clear. Eg what does "when I choose house_id=1
 UserNameA user will have custom_tag, custom_address" mean? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS You seem to have a relation(ship)/association in mind "house id [house_id] has custom tag [custom_tag]" and/or "thing [e] has custom [a] with value [v]". Google EAV. PS Time to read a published academic textbook on information modeling & database design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks on doing information modeling & database design.)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an entity-attribute-value model (EAV).  You would have a table that looks like:

```
house_id    attribute       value
    1       tag             ...
    1       address         ...
    2       country         ...
    2       phone_number    ...
```

Comment: so if I added another user let's say `UserNameB` that means they will have the same value as `UserNameA` when `house_id 1` is chosen?

Comment: @Bazinga Explain why you suspect that. Say what "add userUserNameB" means *exactly*. Better, edit your post to have an example with more users etc to show what you want to do & tell us more clearly what that is & try to use this answer to get desired output.